# EJS page is not loading image

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, html-pdf

I am new to node.js and for this project I a mtrying to load image on ejs file. Images are inside public folder but still its not displaying images on .ejs file. If I call the project with the image url as **localhost:3000/public/images/bmLogo.png** , it displays the image. But if I call the url as **src="/images/bmLogo.png"** on ejs file, its not displaying the image. Is there a way I can display image on .ejs file?

**Folder Path**

```
-- views
   -report-template.ejs
-- public
   -images
     -bmLogo.png
app.js
```

View folder contains report-template.ejs on it and public folder which contains images/bmLogo.png .

**App.js**

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let ejs = require("ejs");
let pdf = require("html-pdf");
let path = require("path");

app.use('/public/', express.static('./public'));
```

**report-template.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="background-color:white; margin-top: -1.5%;">
            <div>
                <img src="/images/bmLogo.png" style="color:black;" alt="image name">
                <p>MIS Pictures</p>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you have this piece of code in app.js:

```js
app.use('/public/', express.static('./public'));
```

The path will be `/public/images/bmLogo.png`, not `/images/bmLogo.png`
So for the  `src` attribute you can change it to `/public/images/bmLogo.png`.
Or, you can do `app.use(express.static("public"))` instead of `app.use('/public/', express.static('./public'));`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue, followed these steps, still wasn't getting anywhere. After trying everything, I changed my file from a .jpg to a .png and it started working.

(This isn't technically an answer to the post, but I wanted to put this out there for if other people are having this problem and I don't have the reputation to leave a comment)

Answer (score 0):

As i tested, in general of node.js using "path.join()" and "process.cwd()" functions for defining path of the files is best practice. you can serve static files such that middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), "/images")));
```

This middleware serves the static files in the "/images" folder. `process.cwd()` function is make the path starts on root folder. it worked as expected in my deployment to the render.